# Apache NiFi with LDAP Convert "User Search Filter" to Uppercase

Tags: ldap, apache-nifi

In Apache NiFi, I would to know how to convert the LDAP "User Search Filter" sAMAccountName={0} to Uppercase because LDAP Account Name is stored in uppercase ?

```
    <property name="User Search Base">OU=Persons,DC=eu,DC=roddata,DC=corp</property>
    <property name="User Search Filter">(sAMAccountName={0})</property>
    <property name="Identity Strategy">USE_USERNAME</property>
```

Thanks

Comment: It really depends on your ldap server, but usually ldap search is case insensitive.

Comment: I don't know if AD supports this (openLDAP should) but you can try `(sAMAccountName:caseIgnoreMatch:={0})`.